# Can you use a namespace while adding to it? Or is that confusing?

Tags: c++, namespaces, using

So I've got a library with many files and each one I want to add to the namespace of my library.  In my declaration of a class I currently have:

```
namespace Vira {

template <typename GeometryT, typename AlbedoT>
class Camera : public Vira::RigidBody<GeometryT> {...};

};
```

This is fine but it feels as if the inside of the declaration gets messy with how many times I need to append `Vira::` before using things.  Would it instead be a good idea to use:

```
using namespace Vira;

namespace Vira {

template <typename GeometryT, typename LightT>
class Camera : public RigidBody<GeometryT> {...};

};
```

Or is this unclear/confusing/bad practice?

This is my first experience working with namespaces.  The closest experience I have is from python where its common practice to `import AnnoyinglyLongName as aln` or something similar.  Which I understand is useful in C++ as well in certain circumstances.  For example, I use the following quite often:

```
template <typename GeometryT>
using Vec3 = Vira::Vector3<GeometryT>;
```

But I'm unsure if its a good idea to broadly use a namespace while I'm adding something to that namespace.

Comment: `using namespace Vira;` is odd. `class Camera : public RigidBody` is good in `namespace Vira {`.

Comment: Oh so, inside of `namespace Vira { ... }` I can use namespace members as if I was `using namespace Vira`?  I didn't realize that.  That'd be a great help

Comment: @ChrisGnam Everything inside a namespace is inside that namespace. Your `using namespace Vira;` makes the names in `Vira` available *outside* of it in that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code inside of a namespace doesn't need to explicitly qualify members of the same namespace.  So, in this code:

```
namespace Vira {

template <typename GeometryT, typename AlbedoT>
class Camera : public Vira::RigidBody<GeometryT> {...};

};
```

The `Vira::` qualification is redundant and can be removed:

```
namespace Vira {

template <typename GeometryT, typename AlbedoT>
class Camera : public RigidBody<GeometryT> {...};

};
```